# how do i write a recursive function that gives all sin values from 0 to 360 degrees

Tags: python, recursion

I need some help, the question says to print sine values from 0 to 360 degrees in a line by line manner so i know we will use `\n`

we have to print the output line by line and store values in a text file. someone please help!!
so far i've only gotten this

```
import math

print (math.sin(30*math.pi/180)) #for 30 degrees
```

Comment: You need a loop, no recursion, because you don't want the function to call itself all over

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 2):

As with all recursion, you need a base case. In this case, we can decrement from `deg` all the way down to zero, effectively treating zero as our base case.

```
def rec_sine(deg):
    if deg == 0:
        return [math.sin(deg*math.pi/180)]
    else:
        return [math.sin(deg*math.pi/180)] + rec_sine(deg-1)
```

Try it out:

```
rec_sine(10)
Out[23]: 
[0.17364817766693033,
 0.15643446504023087,
 0.13917310096006544,
 0.12186934340514748,
 0.10452846326765346,
 0.08715574274765817,
 0.0697564737441253,
 0.05233595624294383,
 0.03489949670250097,
 0.01745240643728351,
 0.0]
```

Comment: Why do you multiply `deg` by `30`?

Comment: Oops.. Should be `math.pi`... Changing now.

Answer (score 1):

To write a file filled with `sin` values, you could use this structure :

```
#encoding: utf-8
from math import sin, pi
with open('sin.txt', 'w') as out:
    for x in range(361):
        out.write('sin(%3d°) = %f\n' % (x, sin(x*pi/180)))
```

It writes a `sin.txt` file :

```
sin(  0°) = 0.000000
sin(  1°) = 0.017452
sin(  2°) = 0.034899
sin(  3°) = 0.052336
sin(  4°) = 0.069756
sin(  5°) = 0.087156
sin(  6°) = 0.104528
sin(  7°) = 0.121869
sin(  8°) = 0.139173
sin(  9°) = 0.156434
sin( 10°) = 0.173648
sin( 11°) = 0.190809
sin( 12°) = 0.207912
sin( 13°) = 0.224951
sin( 14°) = 0.241922
...
...
sin(346°) = -0.241922
sin(347°) = -0.224951
sin(348°) = -0.207912
sin(349°) = -0.190809
sin(350°) = -0.173648
sin(351°) = -0.156434
sin(352°) = -0.139173
sin(353°) = -0.121869
sin(354°) = -0.104528
sin(355°) = -0.087156
sin(356°) = -0.069756
sin(357°) = -0.052336
sin(358°) = -0.034899
sin(359°) = -0.017452
sin(360°) = -0.000000
```

There's no reason at all to use recursion here, especially if you're writing a file.

If for some reason, you really want to do it :

```
#encoding: utf-8
from math import sin, pi

def recursive_sin(x, out, max_x=360):
    if x <= max_x:
        out.write('sin(%3d°) = %f\n' % (x, sin(x*pi/180)))
        recursive_sin(x+1, out)

with open('sin.txt', 'w') as out:
    recursive_sin(0, out)
```

It writes the same `sin.txt` file as the previous example, only opens the file once and closes it at the end of the script. It's still not a good idea, though.